NodeJS instrumentation profiler that records wall clock time of functions
I often find myself wanting to know the breakdown in time taken in a complex script. All of the time is time spent in IO waiting for data from various places.
What i really want is a breakdown of the time spent in every single function, and then the ability to filter.
Does anyone have any recommendations on where to begin writing this tool?
I have tried taking a .cpuprofile, but it is useless for this, as it doesn't show wall clock time.
